# summation of induced representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I do not understand or see the proof of the following fact in Serre's book: If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are induced by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, respectively, then $\rho_1 \oplus \rho_2$ is induced by $\theta_1 \oplus \theta_2$.

I can interpret it as follows:
If $V_1=Ind_{H_1}^G(W_1)$ and $V_2=Ind_{H_2}^G(W_2)$, then there exists a subgroup $H$ such that $V_1 \oplus V_2=Ind_{H}^G(W_1 \oplus W_2)$. But, what is $H$? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Probably the intended meaning is $H_1 = H_2 = H$ but this is ambiguous as stated.

Comment: If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ were representations of different groups then how do you take their direct sum?

Comment: You should ask the author.